# Getting and removing the first character of a string

Tags: string, r

I would like to do some 2-dimensional walks using strings of characters by assigning different values to each character.  I was planning to 'pop' the first character of a string, use it, and repeat for the rest of the string.

How can I achieve something like this?

```
x <- 'hello stackoverflow'
```

I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
a <- x.pop[1]

print(a)

'h'
print(x)

'ello stackoverflow'
```

Answer (score 202, accepted):

See [`?substring`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/topics/substr).

```
x <- 'hello stackoverflow'
substring(x, 1, 1)
## [1] "h"
substring(x, 2)
## [1] "ello stackoverflow"
```

---

The idea of having a `pop` method that both returns a value and has a side effect of updating the data stored in `x` is very much a concept from object-oriented programming.  So rather than defining a `pop` function to operate on character vectors, we can make a [reference class](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/methods/topics/ReferenceClasses) with a `pop` method.

```
PopStringFactory <- setRefClass(
  "PopString",
  fields = list(
    x = "character"  
  ),
  methods = list(
    initialize = function(x)
    {
      x <<- x
    },
    pop = function(n = 1)
    {
      if(nchar(x) == 0)
      {
        warning("Nothing to pop.")
        return("")
      }
      first <- substring(x, 1, n)
      x <<- substring(x, n + 1)
      first
    }
  )
)

x <- PopStringFactory$new("hello stackoverflow")
x
## Reference class object of class "PopString"
## Field "x":
## [1] "hello stackoverflow"
replicate(nchar(x$x), x$pop())
## [1] "h" "e" "l" "l" "o" " " "s" "t" "a" "c" "k" "o" "v" "e" "r" "f" "l" "o" "w"
```

Answer (score 22):

There is also `str_sub` from the stringr package

```
x <- 'hello stackoverflow'
str_sub(x, 2) # or
str_sub(x, 2, str_length(x))
[1] "ello stackoverflow"
```

Answer (score 11):

Use this function from `stringi` package

```
> x <- 'hello stackoverflow'
> stri_sub(x,2)
[1] "ello stackoverflow"
```

Answer (score 11):

`substring` is definitely best, but here's one `strsplit` alternative, since I haven't seen one yet.

```
> x <- 'hello stackoverflow'
> strsplit(x, '')[[1]][1]
## [1] "h"
```

or equivalently

```
> unlist(strsplit(x, ''))[1]
## [1] "h"
```

And you can `paste` the rest of the string back together.

```
> paste0(strsplit(x, '')[[1]][-1], collapse = '')
## [1] "ello stackoverflow"
```

Answer (score 5):

removing first characters:

```
x <- 'hello stackoverflow'
substring(x, 2, nchar(x))
```

Idea is select all characters starting from 2 to number of characters in x. This is important when you have unequal number of characters in word or phrase.

Selecting the first letter is trivial as previous answers:

```
substring(x,1,1)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another alternative is to use capturing sub-expressions with the regular expression functions `regmatches` and `regexec`.

```
# the original example
x <- 'hello stackoverflow'

# grab the substrings
myStrings <- regmatches(x, regexec('(^.)(.*)', x))
```

This returns the entire string, the first character, and the "popped" result in a list of length 1.

```
myStrings
[[1]]
[1] "hello stackoverflow" "h"                   "ello stackoverflow"
```

which is equivalent to `list(c(x, substr(x, 1, 1), substr(x, 2, nchar(x))))`. That is, it contains the super set of the desired elements as well as the full string.

---

Adding `sapply` will allow this method to work for a character vector of length > 1.

```
# a slightly more interesting example
xx <- c('hello stackoverflow', 'right back', 'at yah')

# grab the substrings
myStrings <- regmatches(x, regexec('(^.)(.*)', xx))
```

This returns a list with the matched full string as the first element and the matching subexpressions captured by `()` as the following elements. So in the regular expression `'(^.)(.*)'`, `(^.)` matches the first character and `(.*)` matches the remaining characters.

```
myStrings
[[1]]
[1] "hello stackoverflow" "h"                   "ello stackoverflow" 

[[2]]
[1] "right back" "r"          "ight back" 

[[3]]
[1] "at yah" "a"      "t yah"
```

Now, we can use the trusty `sapply` + `[` method to pull out the desired substrings.

```
myFirstStrings <- sapply(myStrings, "[", 2)
myFirstStrings
[1] "h" "r" "a"
mySecondStrings <- sapply(myStrings, "[", 3)
mySecondStrings
[1] "ello stackoverflow" "ight back"          "t yah"
```

Comment: This is a very nice trick but I think that misses the question.

Comment: You'll need to explain further as it can produce the same output as the other answers. See the final block of code that uses `sapply` for the extraction. "popping" the first character, as specified in the question, is a matter of repeating this process on the resulting vector (mySecondStrings).

Comment: Sure it works with the extra explanation you just added but I still find it more convoluted than it should.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using the sub function.

```
 sub('(^.).*', '\\1', 'hello stackoverflow')
 [1] "h"

 sub('(^.)(.*)', '\\2', 'hello stackoverflow')
 [1] "ello stackoverflow"
```