# Replace all characters after the first in a string

Tags: r

I was wondering if there was a way to use `gsub` to remove all characters except for the first one from a given string.

So if I had `hello`, I would end up with `h`.

Thanks!

Comment: I know you asked for a method using `gsub` but why not `substr(x, start = 1, stop = 1)`?

Answer (score 2):

I could not find an exact dupe for this so here you go,

```
sub('(.).*', '\\1', c('hello'))
#[1] "h"
```

For other methods of extracting the first letter, you can refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723549/getting-and-removing-the-first-character-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1):

I think this would work for you:

```
> substring("hello", 1, 1)
[1] "h"
```