# Remove string from multiple columns only if it is at the start of a string in R

Tags: r, string, substring, stringr, grepl

I have a dataframe that has many columns called fact (in this example, fact1, fact2, and fact3) that have characters. They all start with old_, and I want to remove that. My real dataset has many columns, so I don't want to do it over every one. I saw a solution here [Getting and removing the first character of a string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7723549/getting-and-removing-the-first-character-of-a-string), but when I try to apply it, I get an error.

```
library(tidyverse)
problem <- tibble(name = c("Random", "Silly"), height = c(48, 50), weight = c(95, 102), fact1 = c("old_song_yes", "old_dance_no"), fact2 = c("old_bold_yes", "old_shy_no"), fact3 = c("old_cold_yes", "old_young_yes"))
```

Here's my solution that does not work along with its error message:

```
apply(problem, substring(problem, 5, nchar(problem)))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : argument "FUN" is missing, with no default
```

It's important that it only removes the string from the start; otherwise, in column fact3, for instance, it will look like "cyes" instead of "cold_yes".

Last, in case it helps, I've included what I want the final product to look like here:

```
library(tidyverse)
solution <- tibble(name = c("Random", "Silly"), height = c(48, 50), weight = c(95, 102), fact1 = c("song_yes", "dance_no"), fact2 = c("bold_yes", "shy_no"), fact3 = c("cold_yes", "young_yes"))
```

If you have a tidy solution or one that only goes over the fact columns, I'd especially appreciate it, thank you!

Comment: It still won't work but the error states that `apply` misses a third argument. You passed `substring(...` to the `MARGIN` argument and hence `"FUN" is missing, with no default`. Be careful with `apply` when you work with `data.frame`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One `dplyr` possibility could be:

```
problem %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("fact")), list(~ sub("^old_", "\\1", .)))

  name   height weight fact1    fact2    fact3    
  <chr>   <dbl>  <dbl> <chr>    <chr>    <chr>    
1 Random     48     95 song_yes bold_yes cold_yes 
2 Silly      50    102 dance_no shy_no   young_yes
```

Or:

```
problem %>%
 mutate_at(vars(starts_with("fact")), list(~ substr(., 5, nchar(.))))
```

Answer (score 0):

We may just use `gsub`.

```
problem[] <- Map(gsub, "^old_", "", problem)
problem
#     name height weight    fact1    fact2     fact3
# 1 Random     48     95 song_yes bold_yes  cold_yes
# 2  Silly     50    102 dance_no   shy_no young_yes
```